# How much force is needed to tow an airliner?

Tags: airport, ground-operations

Airliners are often (almost always actually) pushed back by a tug or a tractor to leave the gate. The tug can also tow an aircraft that cannot taxi by itself.

How much force is required to pull or push a large airliner on the ground? In other words, what is the horsepower of these tugs?

**EDIT**: By large airliner, I mean Boeing 747 / 777 / A380 type, the ones which ATC append "Heavy" (or "Super") to their call sign.

[image]

Comment: [There are many types of tug](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=aircraft+tug&biw=1638&bih=815&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2mJP4tMPMAhVpAcAKHWt5B0UQ_AUIBigB) for many types of aircraft.  Are you able to be specific, otherwise the question is a "list".

Comment: Every year at the airshow my company brings an A300 and they tie a rope to the front gear and 15 of us pull it, tug-of-war style.

Comment: Depends on the surface, and whether the tires are inflated properly.

Comment: You asked for force and horsepower, which are different thing. Force should just be $F=\mu N$. HP will be based on how quickly you want to accelerate. Right?

Comment: Moving planes is pretty easy. They are lighter than they look. A single person can drag a twin engine.

Comment: A part of a Toyota ad, they used a Tundra to pull the Space shuttle Endeavour.  While not a "heavy" aircraft, the forces are similar:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AO37TSgKwSg

Comment: @TylerDurden: Twin-engine as in a Cessna 310, or twin-engine as in a 777?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Tugs do not need that much horsepower, even the biggest tugs only have around 400bhp. What they do need is lots of torque for push/pull power, lots of weight to give it plenty of inertia, and big grippy tires to transfer the power to the surface.

The T80 in [this link](http://www.littlebigtugcompany.co.uk/specs.htm) is pretty typical, 50-70 tons, 408bhp, and 1500 pound feet of torque. That's more than triple the torque of a hefty pickup.

Comment: As Carroll Shelby once said, "Horsepower determines how fast you hit the wall, torque determines how far you move it." Think of the plane as a wall that the tug doesn't need to move quickly.

Comment: Why does a tug need inertia? Surely the weight is actually to give as much traction as possible to avoid the tug's wheels slipping when the power id applied.

Comment: It's weight helps to give an even pull, if a tire loses grip it's momentum will help keep the assembly rolling in the same direction.

Comment: Seemed like a reasonable edit, @GdD, especially the "Drawbar Pull" bit. But, it's your answer.

Comment: Thought for a minute you meant the T80 tank!  The tug is actually heavier, is it full of concrete?

Answer (score 17):

It only takes 7030 Kg, 309 BHP, and 553 lb/ft of torque. Well, it does if your tug is a [VW Toureg](http://www.autocar.co.uk/car-news/motoring/touaregs-towing-ability-plane-silly).

[image: https://images.cdn.autocar.co.uk/sites/autocar.co.uk/files/styles/gallery_slide/public/volkswagen-touareg-231166102093.jpg?itok=SAMUMnFS]
<sup>Very pixeley image sourced from link above</sup>
This was a stunt done by the TV Show *Fifth Gear* and *Autocar* magazine. Realistically it doesn't take much, but I wouldn't count on the Toureg for day-to-day movements at JFK, ORD or ATL.

<sup>No, that's not a standard 747-200, [it was modified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-BDXJ) for the James Bond movie *Casino Royale*.</sup>

Comment: My brother still will not believe that they used a modified 747 for that movie. I noticed it immediately when it came out.

Comment: As a random aside, that craft is featured rather heavily in the new/old Top Gear.  They actually did a "drag race" with it once, were Jeremy was tugging it along in a Tractor.  He got last place, it's a huge thing to be pulling...

Comment: @JayCarr, really? Jezza actually lost some sort of Top Gear Challenge? I'm going to have to go re-watch them all to find that one!!

Comment: I don't know where you got your stats from but, [according to Volkswagen](http://media.vw.com/doc/770/78354275952e28a4ace7ae.pdf) a VW Tuareg has a maximum gross weight of 2910kg and puts out at most 406ft-lb of torque (and even that's cheating by taking the maximum weight of one model and the maximum torque of a different one).

Comment: Directly from the linked article, @DavidRicherby.

Comment: @FreeMan Ah. In that case, you should probably say, "If your tug is a VW Tuareg with its weight more than doubled by adding steel ballast." Interesting that that article contradicts VW's own technical specs about the torque of their car's engines.

Comment: @DavidRicherby everything I can find (in a super quick Google) for the **V10** Toureg TDI shows 553lb/ft. Sure you're not looking at the **V6** specs on the VW site?

Answer (score 9):

Actually Boeing (publicly) publishes this data for all of its aircraft in the [Airplane Characteristics for Airport Planning Manuals](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/airports/plan_manuals.page). Here is the chart for the 747-8:

[image]

The "Total Traction Wheel Load" is the required weight of the tug on its drive wheels, while the "Drawbar Pull" is the force on the actual towbar/NLG.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, friction of the wheels, and the slope of the concrete is all you need.
 "Strongmen" pulling buses only have to pull 300 pounds, once static friction is broken.
    [See explanation HERE](http://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/arts/circus-arts/question523.htm)

416,299 pound planes (188.83 tons) like the CC-177 Globemaster III cargo plane can be pulled by It is MUCH BIGGER than a jumbo jet.
Youtube is full of videos of people pulling planes with teeth or "other" body parts.

110 BHP is the rating that the "AIRCRAFT TOWING TRACTOR – MODEL BA10G40" claims. It hauls 737's at up to 25 kmph.
[See full stats HERE](https://firangionindia.wordpress.com/military/indian-army/army-photos/aircraft-towing-tractor-model-ba10g40/)

Comment: If by "jumbo jet" you mean 747, it's much, much (448 tonnes MTOW) bigger than a C-17 (265 tonnes).

Comment: Particularly the second paragraph looks like it needs some editing, but I don't know what was meant to go in there. Please review it and [edit] appropriately.